# Parametrize given curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm given the following curves:

$x = y^2 + 1$, $z = x + 5$

I'm eventually trying to find the unit tangent vector, so I need to find the r vector. Could I just assign $y = t$, and then have $<t^2 + 1, t, t^2 + 6>$?  This doesn't seem right to me, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks right. A parametrization is just that, it doesn't have to be $x=t$, it can be anything so long as you are representing the curve faithfully.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way. In kinematics you are often given a curve in its parametrized form, where the parameter is t(time). Sometimes it is trivial to eliminate the parameter t, but then you only got knowledge of the trajectory of the particle(or body) moving, sometimes it's not. What you are asking here is exactly the opposite. Going your way we  get
$$\vec{r}\left ( t \right )=\left ( t^{2} +1\right )\vec{i}+t\vec{j}+\left(t^{2}+6 \right )\vec{k}$$